# Changing font colour of Twitch Chat in CSS

Tags: css, fonts, stream, chat, twitch

I've been trying to set up some overlays on my stream (using solely OBS), which includes a Twitch Chat overlay. So far I've been able to customize some of it through filters, and I managed to find a snippet that makes the background transparant.

https://gist.github.com/Bluscream/83083d0cd483b3563b5e2b4d55519003

The problem I'm running into is font colour. I'm using a custom background (hence the use of transparancy), which has dark colours. At this time, my chat font stays black, which is barely visible. I'd like to change it to white, but the snippet I'm using does not work for this. Not sure if this information is needed, but the snippet is directly copied in the CSS box on OBS. Does anyone know how to change the font colour of chat messages to white? If any additional information is needed, please ask!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go read How to Ask. and stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

color: white; You have to write it in the css file in the Body class